# Spring JPA automatically fetch system time stamp from database

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to fetch the current system timestamp: `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` automatically every time I run a select operation.

Sample code below:

SomeEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeEntity {
    @Column(name = "name", length = 500)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "current_timestamp")
    private LocalDate currentTimestamp;
}
```

The `currentTimestamp` column is not physically present in the table but I wish to get the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value from the database to be populated in this field every time I perform a SELECT operation as below:

`List<SomeEntity> records = someCrudRepository.findByName("someName")`
OR `List<SomeEntity> records = someCrudRepository.findAll()`

In short, I'd like to run this query via Spring JPA: `SELECT name, current_timestamp FROM some_table;`

Is there any way to achieve the same except using native or jpql queries?

I don't want to use Java time library for getting the timestamp as that is not the overall purpose of getting the current timestamp.

Comment: By the way, `LocalDate` stores only a date, no time of day, no time zone or offset. You may want `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Comment: I won't use this field anywhere so as long as it's internally calling the `current_timestamp` from database it's fine. If that is not the case let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate's `@Formula` is what you are looking for:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;

public class SomeEntity {
    ...

    @Formula("current_timestamp")
    private LocalDate currentTimestamp;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's throwing a SQL compilation error saying that my table doesn't have current_timestamp field

Comment: @saran3h Is it thrown when reading from database or writing to it?

Comment: When reading from database. I made the field Transient but now the value is not picked up when reading the data.